# Powershell BitsTransfer from remote session

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to use PowerShell BitsTransfer to transfer files from a remote session? For instance, without BitsTransfer using only Copy-Item I can do:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName some_server;
Copy-Item -FromSession $session -Path 'C:\RemoteDirectory\file.txt' -Destination 'C:\LocalDirectory\file.txt';
```

But for BitsTransfer there is no equivalent of FromSession parameter:

```
# Works for local files
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "C:\RemoteDirectory\file.txt" -Destination 'C:\LocalDirectory\file.txt';
```

I want to use BitsTransfer because it gives me a nice progress bar for larger files, and that's essentially the only reason I need it. Perhaps there is another way to do it altogether?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNC` pathing to do this.

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source "\\server\C$\RemoteDirectory\file.txt" -Destination "C:\LocalDirectory\"
```

You can also use alternate credentials by using the `-Credential` parameter.